# Add Dynamics CRM HTML Webresource in Power portal

Tags: html, dynamics-crm, portal

I've created an HTML webresource in Dynamics CRM. Now I need to show it in Power Portals. I tried following below links but none of them helped me out.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XaKZUGmhEo&t=8s

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/283638/add-html-webresource-in-portal

Please help me to add HTML web resource in Power Portal.

Comment: What’s the issue you’re facing when you follow the links and it’s contents?

Comment: The webresource didn't get populated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to use a dynamics web resource within a portal (although you probably can). If you want to add your custom HTML to a portal I would use web templates instead.

1. Create a web template with the html inside
2. Create a page template with type = web template and select the web template that you created
3. Create a web page and select the page template that you just created as the page template.